# Serve subfolder location as static if other use rules

Tags: nginx, drupal, single-page-application

I want to use Drupal CMS as main website and my SPA application from mywebsite.com/app.

Drupal has complex NGINX configuration and I don't want to change it.

I need a rule `location /app` serves as static in other cases use rest rules.

Currently it's

```
 location /app {
   alias /other/folder/app;
 }
```

But other rule which serves js and css files for Drupal breaks it

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
  try_files $uri @rewrite;
  expires max;
  log_not_found off;
}
```

I could probably change this rule, but I want to stop NGINX to implement any rules when I serve my app folder for performance and security reasons.

Comment: There is a special modifier for prefix locations that allow to skip regex matching locations checking: `location ^~ /app { ... }`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Create or edit this file public_html/.htacces

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?your-drupal.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?your-drupal.com$

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ app/index.php  [L]
```